# Manipulating Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm doing my homework and there are a couple of things that I am having trouble grasping. All my homework asks is that I simplify the exponents. For example: `6^5 * 6^3 = 6^8`

There are 2 problems I am unsure on what to do. They have to do with multiplying fractions:

`(7^3)^5/6` = `7^5/2` is the answer but I don't understand how they got to that. I know there is a certain example I was shown where you had to get common demonators and such but if I apply that it doesn't turn out well. Same for this problem:

`(7^3/5)^5/6` = `7^2`

`3^5/2 * 3^-2` = `3^1/2`

Comment: Use some parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x$, $a$, and $b$.

$(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$.

Hence for the first one, letting $x = 7$, $a = 3$, $b = \frac{5}{6}$, you have

$(7^3)^{\frac{5}{6}} = 7^{3 \cdot \frac{5}{6}} = 7^{\frac{5}{2}}$

For the second letting $x = 7$, $a = \frac{3}{5}$ and $b = \frac{5}{6}$, you have

$(7^{\frac{3}{5}})^{\frac{5}{6}} = 7^{\frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{5}{6}} = 7^{\frac{3}{6}} = 7^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

---

For the last one, for any $x$, $a$ and $b$

$(x^a)(x^b) = x^{a + b}$.

Letting $x = 3$, $a = \frac{5}{2}$ and $b = -2$, you have

$(3^{\frac{5}{2}})(3^{-2}) = 3^{\frac{5}{2} + -2} = 3^{\frac{5}{2} + \frac{-4}{2}} = 3^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: so from the looks of you you just put 3/1 and cross divided to get 5/2?

Comment: @AlexMiller It's a normal arithmetic. $3 \times \frac{5}{6} = 15 \div 6 = \frac{5}{2}.$

Comment: @AlexMiller That just how to multiply fractions. $3 \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{15}{6} = \frac{5}{2}$. By the way, I have never heard of the term cross divide.

Comment: I see I'm over complicating it, just multiply across, denominator  and nominator then simplify. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, 
$$(a^b)^c=a^{(bc)}.$$
 Let us apply that to your first example. We have
$$(7^3)^{\frac{5}{6}}=7^{\left(3\cdot \frac{5}{6}\right)}.$$
But $3\cdot \frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The exponent rules are boookkeeping. You need to keep track of the number of powers being used. For example,
$$x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$$ 
because there are a total of $a+b$ factors of $x$ here.  The other important tool is
$$\left(x^a\right)^b = x^{ab}.$$
Again, this is bookkeeping.

Hence, in your example
$$\left(7^{3/5}\right)^{5/6} = 7^{{3/5}\cdot{5/6}} = 7^{1/2} = \sqrt{7}.  $$